# How to calculate sine and cosine without importing math?

Tags: python

I started programming in python not too long ago and I am having trouble with a part of a program. The program will ask for input from the user and he can input: A, B, C, M, or Q. I have completed the A, M, and Q part but I can't figure out how to do the parts for B (calculate the sine of the number you want) and C (calculate the sine).
All the information I was given was:

> The power series approximation for the sine of X can be expressed as:
>   sine(X) = X – (X3/3!) + (X5/5!) – (X7/7!) + (X9/9!) .... Note that an
>   individual term in that power series can be expressed as: (-1)k *
>   X2k+1 / (2k+1)! where k = 0, 1, 2, 3, ….

Oooh, and (but for this a while loop should do right?): 
When computing the sine of X or the cosine of X, the program will expand the power series
until the absolute value of the next term in the series is less than 1.0e-8 (the specified epsilon).
That term will not be included in the approximation.

And I can't use import math.
Can anyone give me an idea of how I can do this? I sincerely have no idea of where to even start hahaha.

Thanks in advance!

***Hey guys, I've been trying to do this for the last 3 hours. I'm really new to programming and some of yours answers made it a bit more understandable for me but my program is not working, I really don't know how to do this. And yes, I went to speak with a tutor today but he didn't know either. So yeah, I guess I'll just wait until I get the program graded by my teacher and then I can ask him how it was supposed to be done. Thank you for all the answers though, I appreciate them! :)

Comment: The question tells you exactly what to do. Add up terms of the Taylor series until you reach a term that's less than 10^-8, and then return the sum.

Comment: How would you do this by hand on paper? Write out the steps, then find the pattern and write it as a loop. This isn't a programming question, more of a math question.

Comment: Start with the `while` loop.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> e = 2.718281828459045
>>> X = 0.1
>>> (e**(X*1j)).imag   # sin(X)
0.09983341664682815
>>> (e**(X*1j)).real   # cos(X)
0.9950041652780258
```

Verify

```
>>> from math import sin, cos
>>> sin(X)
0.09983341664682815
>>> cos(X)
0.9950041652780258
```

You'll probably get better marks if you sum up the series explicitly though

```
result = 0
n = 1
while True:
    term = ...
    result += term
    if term <= epsilon:
        break
    n += 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you aren't supposed to import `math` because you are supposed to write your own function to compute sine.  You are supposed to use the power series approximation.

I suggest you start by writing a factorial function, then write a loop that uses this factorial function to compute the power series.

If you still can't figure it out, I suggest you talk to your teacher or a teacher's assistant.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a condition to finish the loop `last_term < 1.0e-8`, you should use a `while`:

```
while last_term > 1.0e-8:
```

You will need a counter to keep the count of `k` (starting from 0) and a variable to keep the last term:

```
k = 10 # some initial value
last_term = 0
while ...:
    last_term = ... # formula here
```

and also a result variable, let' say `sin_x`:

```
while ...:
    ...
    sin_x += last_term
```

**Note:** In the formula you are using factorial, so will need to define a function that computes the factorial of a number, and use it properly.